# Send array from postman and validate with express validator in Node JS

Tags: node.js, arrays, postman, express-validator

In Node js, i am using express validator to validate the request body of an API.
I have one file `validators.js` where I define validators for an API request.
I want to validate `inviteesArray` which needs to be in below format:

```
//expected
[
  {"userId" :"07aeb7ff-bf11-4a64-b842-a6fe1aa0a7f6"},
  {"userId" :"7b89059a-3915-4d1d-b55c-077260f07021"}
];
```

my validator:

```
body('inviteesArray','inviteesArray is required!').if((value, { req }) => req.body.isInvited !== "false").isArray().notEmpty(),
```

request in postman, which gives validation error, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
**UPDATE**
when i change my validator with removing the if condition it works.
    body('inviteesArray','inviteesArray is required!').if((value, { req }) => console.log(value)).isArray().notEmpty(),
```

Comment: you can use `Application/JSON` in `raw` tab

Comment: @aRvi i could have used that but i also have image and video upload in request and that is not possible with `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

You hove to add object keys inside braces to pass as an array of object

```
KEY                       VALUE
invitesArray[0][userId]   first value
invitesArray[1][userId]   second value
```